# Some mappings in my .vim/ftplugin/*.vim change upon entering a window with different filetype, and some don't. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, filetype, plugin-system

I have special commenting macros for different languages in my `ftplugin` files, and macros for creating "dividers" (i.e. commented out line of dashes `#--------...`). I also define a Vimscript filetype for `.vimrc` and files ending in `.vim` using an entry in `.vim/ftdetect`.

For some reason, when I switch between tabs/windows, my commenting macro **changes** but my "insert divider" macro **does not change** (i.e. the comment character for the former macro is modified, but the comment character for the latter is not).

Any possible reasons for this? Sorry if this seems vague but I'm at a loss here.

---

Here are the macros; I have no idea how they could possibly be different enough to invoke this reaction.

Matlab remaps:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c mA^i%<Esc>`A
nnoremap <Leader>_ mAo%<Esc>100a-<Esc>`A
```

Vimscript remaps:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c mA^i"<Esc>`A
nnoremap <Leader>_ mAo"<Esc>100a-<Esc>`A
```

Comment: Are you aware of autocommand? They get executed when an event happens.

Comment: Yes but I've heard to prevent clutter it is perhaps better practice to use `filetype plugin on` and define filetype-specific macros in the relevant files within. Maybe I'll go back to how I did it before. 

Also I'm trying now to write just one generalized macro which uses `exeucte normal!` with a "comment character" (another thread), but still wondering why the hell one remap would be done and another not done.

Comment: @SibiCoder It never ceases to amaze me the faith some of you guys seem to have in `autocmd`s.  They are a crappy kludge, and a fragile one at that.  It's almost always better to use `ftplugin`s instead of `autocmd`s when possible.  `ftplugin`s are still implemented as `autocmd`s, but at least they happen at the right time.

Comment: See `:h :map-<buffer>`.  Also, use `:verbose nnoremap <Leader>c` to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks! That's what I needed. I ended up writing a generalized comment macro that uses a "comment character" global variable declared by ftplugin files; but will be sure to use `<buffer>` for any future filetype-specific remaps.